# Colab notebook save keeps failing

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colab keeps telling me that the notebook has been changed outside of my session despite not having any other tabs open with this notebook and so I have to keep "overwriting" the changes made by these non-existent tabs.

Is this a known bug? Is there any solution?